# override the return type of method declared in the interface after its implemented in class

Tags: java, generics

My requirement is I have an Interface where one method is declared and two classes implement the same interface, in which one class has return type of `Set<object type>` and other `LIST<object type>`... please help me in correcting the code mistakes.

Here is the example code below :

**Report file** --- interface

```
public interface Reportfile
{
    public <T> parseReadfile();
}
```

**Masterfile.java ---- class one**

```
public class Masterfile implements Reportfile
    {
Set<Masterpojo > mset = new TreeSet<Masterpojo>();

        public String[] newline = null;
        public Set<Masterpojo> parseReadfile()
            {
                try{
                    Masterpojo mo = new Masterpojo();
                    CSVReader mread = new CSVReader(new FileReader(mfile),(delimiter));
                    while ((newline = mread.readNext()) != null)
                        {           
                            mo.setmline(newline);               
                            mset.add(mo);
                        }
                }catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        log.error("file not found");
                    }
                return mset;
            }
    }
```

**Transfile.java ---- class 2**

```
public class Transfile implements Reportfile
    {

List<Transpojo> tlist = new ArrayList<Transpojo>();

        public String[] newline = null;

        public List<Transpojo> parseReadfile()
            {
                try{
                    Transpojo to = new Transpojo();
                    CSVReader tread = new CSVReader(new FileReader(Transfile),(delimiter));
                    while ((newline = tread.readNext()) != null)
                        {
                            to.settline(newline);   
                            tlist.add(to);
                        }
                }catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        log.error("Transaction file not found");
                    }
                return tlist;
            }
    }
```

**Masterpojo**

```
public class Masterpojo
    {
        public String[] mline = null;       
        public String[] getmline()
            {
                return mline;
            }
        public void setmline(String[] mline)
            {
                this.mline = mline;
            }       
    }
```

**Transpojo**

```
public class Transpojo
    {

        public String[] tline = null;

        public String[] gettline()
            {
                return tline;
            }
        public void settline(String[] tline)
            {
                this.tline = tline;
            }   

    }
```

I error like belo when I compile the code in cmd :

```
Masterfile.java:6: error: Masterfile is not abstract and does not override abstract method <E>parseReadfi
le() in Reportfile
public class Masterfile implements Reportfile
       ^
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in method <E>parseReadfile()
Masterfile.java:34: error: parseReadfile() in Masterfile cannot implement <E>parseReadfile() in Reportfil
e
                public Set<Masterpojo> parseReadfile()
                                       ^
  return type Set<Masterpojo> is not compatible with void
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in method <E>parseReadfile()
Transfile.java:7: error: Transfile is not abstract and does not override abstract method <E>parseReadfile
() in Reportfile
public class Transfile implements Reportfile
       ^
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in method <E>parseReadfile()
Transfile.java:33: error: parseReadfile() in Transfile cannot implement <E>parseReadfile() in Reportfile
                public List<Transpojo> parseReadfile()
                                       ^
  return type List<Transpojo> is not compatible with void
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in method <E>parseReadfile()
4 errors
```

Comment: Please ass you interface's code

Comment: I have added it now...sorry forgot that...please take a look at it....

Comment: When i compile the report file alone i get this error below : Reportfile.java:4: error: <identifier> expected
                public < T > parseReadfile();
                                          ^
1 error

Comment: Your interface doesn't compile.

Comment: yes, when I tried to compile all the codes at once, during that time i get the above error for the interface also i changed the interface code as how  NecroTheif as said below. but even then i get the error.

Comment: You should KNOW what you want the interface to return. Just finding the appropriate signature so that both classes implement the interface is backward reasoning. The interface should define the contract, and the subclasses should comply to it. It seems that you have two unrelated classes, and you want them to implement an interface, whatever the contract of that interface is. What's the point?

Comment: Sorry this is my first excercise that i am doing in Java...Ik now only basics in java...So i struggle a lot to understand how to combine all the logics together....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public interface Reportfile<T>
{
    public T parseReadFile();
}

public class Masterfile implements Reportfile<Set<Masterpojo>> 
{
    public Set<Masterpojo> parseReadfile()
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class Transfile implements Reportfile<List<Transpojo>> 
{
    public List<Transpojo> parseReadfile()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

However, your code contains massive duplication ! Look at `Transpojo` and `Masterpojo`. The are exactly the same ! (except naming)
Look at `Masterfile` and `Transfile`, both `parseReadFile` are implemented in the exact same way ! Except that one returns a `Set` and the other a `List`. All this can be simplified into something like (generics are not needed anymore):

```
public interface Reportfile
{
    public Collection<Pojo> parseReadFile();
}

public final class CsvFile implements Reportfile {
    @Override
    public Collection<Pojo> parseReadFile() {
        Collection<Pojo> result = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] newline;
        try {
            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(file), delimiter);
            while ((newline = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                result.add(new Pojo(newline));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("file not found");
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

With `Pojo`:

```
public final class Pojo {
    private final String[] line;

    public Pojo(String[] line) {
        this.line = line;
    }

    public String[] getLine() {
        return line;
    }
}
```

Comment: got compiled properly....But please can someone explain me the concept of generics...I find it hard to learned in internet as i couldnt understand it

Comment: @Svati When you declare a method with a return value of type T, it means that this type can only be known at runtime when someone will decide to call this method by substituting T by any concrete type (Integer, Double, File, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Your Interface should declare what T is for the method parseReadfile (not the method itself) so if you make it so T is a generic type of ReportFile you can declare it in the classes that implement it.

For ReportFile.java

```
public interface Reportfile<T> { public < T > parseReadfile(); }
```

For Masterfile.java

```
public class Masterfile implements Reportfile<Masterpojo>
```

For Transfile.java

```
public class Transfile implements Reportfile<Transpojo>
```

You also have to change the method to return T not get T now like so:

```
public T parseReadfile();
```

Comment: Sorry forgot to add the interface file...I have added it now...please take a look at it....

Comment: Updated my answer to fit

Comment: Yes T is the generic type which i am trying since Master and trans file class has different return types in their parseReadfile method .But still I get the error for the Reportfile like :                                       Reportfile.java:4: error: <identifier> expected
                public < T > parseReadfile();
                                          ^
1 error

Comment: Sorry, forget to mention that you have to return T in your method. Edit fixed it.

Comment: can you please explain me the basics involved in generics....like why do we use < > in class and in method only T...I learned in internet but find it difficult to understand...I know that generics can be used to override the return type..that is it...

Comment: <T> means to use the method, class, or interface you have to define what T is. Just using T means you are referencing whatever T was set to when the method, class, interface was created/called. Look [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) for more info.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94290/discussion-between-necrotheif-and-svati).